# Wont allow me to resize IFrame window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, asp.net-mvc-2

Creating a web application using asp.net mvc 2.

Attempting to add an iframe inside the Index page.

```
<div id="root">
    <iframe src='http://restOfUrl' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>
</div>
```

Iframe loads page inside 100% of width but only about 20% of height.
Tried adding multiple `<br/>` above and below iframe tag to see if it has made any difference. 
Page has expanded in height but iframe has remainded the same.

Please advise?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Just give the 80% or 100% height to the parent element in your case

```
root{
   height:80%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9akc2jpy/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/9akc2jpy/)

Answer (score 1):

height in % is depended on the parent element. if the parent element doesn't have a height set it will fail.

so there are 2 sollutions.

1. give parent div a height like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/ns2vy6sx/

or 2. set the height in px, like so:

```
<div id="root" >
    <iframe src='http://restOfUrl' width='100%' height='500px'></iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ns2vy6sx/1/

Comment: no problem @John, reminder for you - if you are using the px solution your webpage will not be liquid. Meaning, if you downsize the window of your webppage the iframe will still be '500px'! if this was your correct answer, could you tag my answer as the solution :)